# Python 2.7.2 as default on Debian 5 Lenny, for Django app

Tags: python, django, debian

I have done **altinstall** from Python 2.7 source and created an 'update-alternatives' links.

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-2.7.2.tgz
cd Python-2.7.2
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

After

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python2.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.5 1
```

In the shell it runs well:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 19 2012, 11:09:25) 
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But Django debug mode still tells me:

> Python Version: 2.5.2

**How to set Python 2.7.2 as default on Debian 5 Lenny for Django app?**

Comment: Are you using apache and mod_wsgi? If so, you may have to compile mod_wsgi against python 2.7.2. (i.e.: ./configure --with-python=/opt/python2.72/bin/python, while using your path to python 2.7.2) as well you may put this in apache httpd.conf: WSGIPythonHome /opt/python2.7 (again with your path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a virtual environment [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org) and when you create the virtualenv you can pass in --python=/usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python2.7 which will create the virtualenv with python 2.7.

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7/bin/python2.7 myvirtualenv
```

Then use the virtualenv you created to install all your requirements, including django, via [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org). Then when you want to run django, make sure you activate your VirtualENV, and you will be using the python2.7 in it's own python environment. You won't be effecting the system python at all, and everything should work the way you want.

To make managing the virtualenv's easier you can use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org)

Answer (score 1):

[Do I lose anything by using Python 2.6 versus newer Python versions, such as Python 2.7?](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.X/faq/install.html#do-i-lose-anything-by-using-python-2-5-versus-newer-python-versions-such-as-python-2-6-or-2-7)

Comment: By and large, only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Debian provides a way to do that, 'stability' and all that, if it considers python a core thing.  Maybe build custom versions of everything in /usr/local/ or upgrade your Debian.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything", aside from python ?